# Google Calendar API returns Daily Limit error

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I get the following error when trying to access the Calendar API

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

However, I checked the google developer console and I am nowhere near hitting my limit (I'm at 2,500 queries when the max is 1,000,000). Also, I don't see how I am not authenticated because I use the OAuth 2.0 credentials to make the api call.

Answer (score -1):

Check the **status** of the Google Calendar API from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=) if it is enabaled.
Then wait for a few minutes after turning the API. You must ensure that you will get a new token each time before trying it.

You can also follow the suggested action that will help you about [Google Calendar API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) error.